# Difference between isothermal and polytropic

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Apart from the fact that isothermal is special case of polytropic equation when $n = 1$, what is the difference between those process in thermodynamic?

is the temperature on polytropic process also kept constant?

Comment: No.  The temperature and pressure are varied in tandem through the process, such that $PV^n$  remains constant.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**:

Isothermal process are a subset of the polytropic. Polytropic encompass all other common processes and more.

**Elaborate answer**:

Polytropic process got their name from the polytrope equation used to model them linking the pressure $P$ and the density $\rho$: $$P=\frac{k}{\rho^n}$$
For ideal gases with a constant number of particles, polytropic processes are the general case described by the equation: $$PV^n=C$$ standard notation implying $C$ is a constant, $P$ the pressure and $V$ the volume. The factor $n$ gives you the type of process happening and the relation between head and work flow.

- If $n=0$ you get $P=C$ so you are in isobaric case.
- If $n=1$ as $PV=Nk_BT$ at equilibrium, you are in the isothermal case.
- If $n\rightarrow \infty$ you get $V=\left(\frac{C}{P}\right)^{1/n}=C'$ which is isochore case (no work flow).
- If $n = \frac{C_P}{C_V} =\gamma$ you are in the adiabatic case (no heat flow)

In the general usage in thermodynamics, a polytropic process is one in which you are out of the special cases and in which you have to check both work and heat flows. Polytrope equations ($P=k/V^n$) have other application in other fields but I don't know enough to talk about them in detail.